# Automatically terminate class while children still reference it

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a class where its children hold a necessary reference to their parent. This means, when the parent class goes out of scope in the routine which calls it, its terminate code is not called, as the children still hold a reference to it.

Is there a way of terminating the parent without having to manually terminate the children first too?

Current work around is to make the parent's terminate code (which contains code to terminate the children) public and to call it from the routine, but this is not ideal as then the parent is terminated twice (once manually, once when it leaves the caller sub's scope). But mainly I don't like having to call it manually

```
'Caller code
Sub runTest()
    Dim testClass As parentClass
    Set testClass = New parentClass
    Set testClass = Nothing
End Sub

'parentClass
Private childrenGroup As New Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim childA As New childClass
    Dim childB As New childClass
    childA.Setup "childA", Me 'give name and parent reference to child class
    childB.Setup "childB", Me
    childrenGroup.Add childA 'add children to collection
    childrenGroup.Add childB
End Sub

Public Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set childrenGroup = Nothing
    Debug.Print "Parent terminated"
End Sub

'childClass
Private className As String
Private parent As classParent

Public Sub Setup(itemName As String, parentObj As classParent)
    Set parent = parentObj 'set the reference
    className = itemName
End Sub

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = className
End Property

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print Name;" was terminated" 'only called when parent terminates child
End Sub
```

Calling `runTest()` prints

```
childA was terminated
childB was terminated
Parent terminated
Parent terminated 'to get around this, you could just make another sub in the parent class
                  'to terminate its children
                  'but that still requires a manual call
```

Comment: I don't believe what you are asking is possible. You'd have to kill off those children manually before the parent is disposed of. Are you sure about your code structure though? Is it not possible to access those child classes from the parent's collection? It seems odd to have a parent collection of children and then have the parent object passed to the children.

Comment: @Ambie  Reading your comment, I do wonder whether I'm giving good or bad advice in providing a technical fix that (probably) does what our inquisitor wants to do. There *are* cases where you want a 'parent' reference in every child, but that kind of programming problem is best solved in a language with Garbage Collection rather than a reference counter. So my answer may be technically-correct and operationally Wrong with a Capital 'W'.

Comment: @Ambie Agreed it does seem odd. But it is a necessary work around since VBA classes can't support groups of events or callback functions. When my child class would ideally raise an event to the parent, I instead have to call a function in the parent, meaning the children require some sort of reference to it. I think Nigel Heffernan's answer approximates what I'm after either way; the context leading to my code structure is perhaps out of scope of the question so I left it out.

Comment: It might be worth editing this or posting a new question to include the events aspect. It sounds as though you're after a delegate class - might be a better way to handle your object disposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having reviewed your comments, I'm still not convinced you need to pass the parent into the child class. If your only reason for doing so is to create a kind of callback then you'd probably be better off passing an event delegate class to the child instead of the parent class and then simply handle the *delegate's* events in your parent class. As you've seen, your current structure is causing some object disposal issues and these can be avoided.

Simply create a class containing your child events. In this example I've called the class *clsChildEvents*:

```
Option Explicit

Public Event NameChange(obj As clsChild)

Public Sub NotifyNameChange(obj As clsChild)
    RaiseEvent NameChange(obj)
End Sub
```

Now your code remains pretty much as is. The key difference is that you are passing the delegate instead of the parent to the child objects.

**Parent class:**

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mChildEvents As clsChildEvents
Private mChildren As Collection

Public Sub SetUp()
    Dim child As clsChild
    
    Set child = New clsChild
    child.SetUp "ChildA", mChildEvents
    mChildren.Add child
    
    Set child = New clsChild
    child.SetUp "ChildB", mChildEvents
    mChildren.Add child
    
End Sub

Private Sub mChildEvents_NameChange(obj As clsChild)
    Debug.Print "New name for "; obj.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mChildEvents = New clsChildEvents
    Set mChildren = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "Parent terminated."
End Sub
```

**Child class:**

```
Option Explicit

Private mClassName As String
Private mEvents As clsChildEvents

Public Sub SetUp(className As String, delegate As clsChildEvents)
    Set mEvents = delegate
    Me.Name = className
End Sub
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = mClassName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(RHS As String)
    mClassName = RHS
    mEvents.NotifyNameChange Me
End Property

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print mClassName; " terminated."
End Sub
```

And then your module code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim parent As clsParent
    
    Set parent = New clsParent
    parent.SetUp
    
    Set parent = Nothing
End Sub
```

The immediate window output is as follows:

> New name for ChildA
>
> New name for ChildB
>
> Parent terminated.
>
> ChildA terminated.
>
> ChildB terminated.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't automatically terminate the children by simply terminating the collection:

```
Public Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set childrenGroup = Nothing
```

The Collection object does not clean up any object references when it is set equal to `Nothing`, and it doesn't have a 'RemoveAll' mechanism which does.

...And I wouldn't bet on 'Remove' doing that either, one item at a time. So you do indeed need to loop backwards through the members, in exactly the 'manual' process you're trying to avoid:

```
Public Sub Class_Terminate()
Dim i As Integer

    For i = childrenGroup.Count To 1 Step - 1
        Set childrenGroup(i) = Nothing
        childrenGroup.Remove i
    Next I

    Set childrenGroup = Nothing
```

My advice would be: **use a Scripting.Dictionary object** instead of the VBA Collection:

```
Private childrenGroup As New Scripting.Dictionary
```

You'll need a reference to the Scripting Runtime (or to the Windows Scripting Host Object Model) and you may be surprised by the changed order of `.Add Item, Key` - and you will *definitely* be surprised by what happens when you request an item with a non-existent key.

Nevertheless, this works. The Dictionary does have a RemoveAll method, and this **will** clear all the references in its .Items when you call it:

```
Public Sub Class_Terminate()
    childrenGroup.RemoveAll
```

You do need to call RemoveAll - it doesn't happen automatically if the dictionary goes out of scope - but that's as close as you'll get.

Note, also, that VBA runs on reference counting: if anything else has a reference to the children, the objects won't be released.